# Lagrangian and finding equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, symmetry-breaking

I am given the following lagrangian:
$L=-\frac{1}{2}\phi\Box\phi\color{red}{ +} \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$
and the questions asks:

- How many constants c can you find for which $\phi(x)=c$ is a solution to the equations of motion? Which solution has the lowest energy (ground state)?
- My attempt:
  since lagrangian is second order we have the following for the equations of motion:
  $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial^\mu \phi)}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_\mu \partial x_\nu}\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial(\partial^\mu \phi)\partial(\partial^\nu \phi)}=0 $$
  then the second term is zero since lagrangian is independent of the fist order derivative. so we will end up with:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}=-\frac{1}{2} \Box \phi+m^2\phi-\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3$$
and:$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_\mu \partial x_\nu}\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial(\partial^\mu \phi)\partial(\partial^\nu \phi)}=-\frac{1}{2}\Box\phi$$
so altogether we have for the equations of motion:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\Box\phi+m^2\phi-\frac{\lambda}{6}\phi^3-\frac{1}{2}\Box\phi=0$$
and if $\phi=c$ where "c" is a constant then $\Box\phi=0$ and then the equation reduces to $$m^2\phi-\frac{\lambda}{6}\phi^3=0$$ which for $\phi=c$ gives us 3 solutions:$$c=-m\sqrt{\frac{6}{\lambda}}\\c=0\\c=m\sqrt{\frac{6}{\lambda}}$$
My question is is my method and calculations right and how do I see which one has the lowest energy (ground state)? so I find the Hamiltonin for that?

Comment: I have also found that since the first two terms look like kinetic terms and the last terms looks like interaction term my hamiltonian looks like: $$H=-\frac{1}{2}\phi\Box\phi +\frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2 +\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$$ and for energies I have :$$c=+/- m\sqrt{\frac{6}{\lambda}}--> E=\frac{9}{2}\frac{m^4}{\lambda}\\c=0--> E=0$$ is it right? so that c=0 has the lowest energy.

Comment: This is Problem 3.5 in Schwartz's QFT textbook.

Comment: yes it is I have mentioned that I'm using Schwartz book in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good so far.  To find the Hamiltonian you just use that if $L = T - U$ then $H = T + U$ (technically there are some extra assumptions there, but if your case it works out fine).  Since $T = 0$ if $\phi$ is constant, you just need to find out which of those values $c$ minimize(s) the potential energy $-1/2 m^2 \phi^2 + \lambda/4! \phi^4$.

Comment: but isn't $-\frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2$ a kinetic terms

Comment: @MSB No, it's quadratic, but not kinetic.  The kinetic terms are the ones with derivatives.

Comment: Thank you parker, @tparker I got a bit confused as my textbook "Matthew D. Schwartz QFT" classifies them as kinetic bilinear terms on page 30 of its book.

Comment: I don't have that book so I can't comment on whether he's wrong or you're misinterpreting it, but the $1/2 m^2 \phi^2$ is definitely a potential energy term, even though it's not an interaction.  Just like the simple harmonic oscillator.  PS I disagree with an important relative sign in Sean Lake's expression for $E$.

Comment: You made an important sign error as well: in writing your equation of motion, you went from having the $\phi^2$ and $\phi^4$ terms having the opposite sign to having the same sign.  So your final answer is incorrect.

Comment: there was a minus sign typing error but for the rest of calculation i cant see where I did mistake.

Comment: @tparker Not just any derivatives, time derivatives. Terms with only space derivatives are potential energy stored in the variations of the field with space.

Comment: Also, @MSB is right about that sign, I mixed it up in my post. The problem he's looking at is the prototype for looking at kink solitons, so it needs to have two minima in the potential.

Comment: @MSB Your $c$'s are fine, but in going from Lagrangian to Hamiltonian you need to change the sign of the $1/2 m^2 \phi^2$ term because it's a potential term.

Comment: Thank you again @tparker,  there is one last thing that I would like to ask, in the b part of this problem it says that lagrangian has a symmetry under $\phi->-\phi$. how do I show that this symmetry is not respected by the ground state with negative mass term? I guess it has to do with having a negative number under the square root but how do I show it?

Comment: @MSB It's because in a real system, the ground state will either have $c = m \sqrt{6/\lambda}$ or $c = -m \sqrt{6/\lambda}$.  Whichever one it "chooses", the symmetry will be broken because the transformation $\phi \to -\phi$ will take you to the *other* ground state.

Comment: @MSB As a rough analogy, it's like flipping a coin.  Before you flip it, the probability of getting heads or tails is exactly 50-50, so the problem is completely symmetric under the interchange of the concepts of "heads" and "tails".  But after you flip it, it will either have heads up or tails up, and the "symmetry operation" of exchanging heads and tails will be broken.

Answer (score 2):

You have a minor error from a missing minus sign here:$$\frac{1}{2}\Box\phi+m^2\phi-\frac{\lambda}{6}\phi^3-\frac{1}{2}\Box\phi.$$ It should be (after combining terms):
$$-\Box\phi+m^2\phi-\frac{\lambda}{6}\phi^3.$$

Now, for finding the Hamiltonian you might find it easier to integrate the term $\phi \Box \phi / 2$ by parts to get $-\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi / 2 + \mathrm{surface\ term}$. That way you can use standard formulae for constructing the Hamiltonian using canonical momenta. That is, assuming you want to construct the Hamiltonian. This Lagrangian has a fairly simple structure with a kinetic energy term (time derivatives of $\phi$), and every other term is potential energy. So, since these states are constant in time and space, their energy will be just potential energy:$$E = \int \left[-\frac{m^2}{2} \phi^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4\right] \operatorname{d}^3 x.$$

Edit: fix my own sign error.

Comment: Thank you Sean, Is that minus sign gonna affect my constant "c" values?

Comment: Nope, because that term drops out, that's why it's minor.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all you guys I have found that my mistake was at confusing the kinetic and interaction terms. so here is my answer to this question:
this problem is basically finding the values for $\phi$ that minimizes the effective potential and I have found them above named $c_1$,$c_2$ and $c_3$ considering those are correct, I have for my effective potential now:
$$V(\phi)=-\frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$$since $L=KE-V$ then my Hamiltonian will be $$H=-\frac{1}{2}\phi\Box\phi -\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$$ for c=0 its just gonna give me zero but for $c=\pm \sqrt{\frac{6m^2}{\lambda}}$ now substituting this into the hamiltonain:$$<H>=E=0-\frac{1}{2}m^2(\sqrt{\frac{6m^2}{\lambda}})^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}(\sqrt{\frac{6m^2}{\lambda}})^4\\E=\frac{m^4}{\lambda}(-\frac{6}{2}+\frac{36}{4!})\\E=\frac{m^4}{\lambda}(-\frac{6}{2}+\frac{3}{2})\\E=-\frac{3}{2}\frac{m^4}{\lambda}$$ so there are two solutions that have the lowest energy which is $c=\phi=\pm\sqrt{\frac{6m^2}{\lambda}}$.

Answer (score 0):

is just want to add to this discussion that book has no type error according to page 30 kinetic terms are billinear meaning that they have exactly two fields so kinetic terms in this case are:

```
T=−1/2(ϕ□ϕ)+1/2(m2ϕ2)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics.SE! Please use [Mathjax](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/804/is-there-a-standard-place-to-point-people-to-learn-how-to-typeset-their-equation) to typeset your equations.